# How performant is collision detection in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection, sprite

I'm gonna be using `hitTestObject()` for quite a lot sprites each frame (e.g. `4 * 500`). There will be many false and only a few or none true.

I thought I might check distances `sprite1.x - sprite2.x` and `sprite1.y - sprite2.y` first so that I let only near objects to be checked for collision. Then I wondered does ActionScript routines already check for distances first ? Flash is optimized in many ways so do I have to bother to increase performance for collision detection ?

```
// something like this ?

public static function near(sprite1: Sprite, sprite2: Sprite): Boolean
{
    return (Math.abs(sprite1.x - sprite2.x) < 64) && (Math.abs(sprite1.y - sprite2.y) < 64);
}

if (near(sprite1, sprite2))
    if (sprite1.hitTestObject(sprite2))
        collide(sprite1, sprite2);
```

Comment: Try it out. It's not that hard to swap out hitTest for a distance check. Would be good for you to gauge it's performance for your own personal knowledge. Google  "as3 collision performance hitTestObject" and I'm quite certain you'll find a wealth of very detailed information on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `hitTestObject()` is not optimized this way. So, if you can lower the amount of `hitTestObject()` calls, do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want performance on many objects you should try shape collisions instead. If you don't want to code it yourself, just take a look at [Box2D](http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/) or [Nape](http://napephys.com/). Both engines have been heavily optimised to do those kind of calculatons.

Comment: "pixel perfect collision" is wrong [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject()). I testes 2 circles. Their bounding boxes collide but not the drawn circles.

Comment: You are right, I was mistaken and I will edit my answer. The logic of the answer still stays true though. `hitTestObject()` is not as optimised as Box2D or Nape.